# How to detect the div where we in using javascript drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, drag, detection

this is my javascript code
`

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("class",ev.target.classList);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var classs = ev.dataTransfer.getData("class");
        if(data === "body") {
            document.getElementById('div1').className = '';
            document.getElementById('div1').classList.add(classs);
        }
        if(data === "table"){
            document.getElementById('myTable').className = '';
            document.getElementById('myTable').classList.add(classs);
        }
        if(data === "font"){
            document.getElementById('myTable').classList.add(classs);
        }
    }`
```

as you can see i just get div that i code based on id that i set in element that i want drag and drop, how to detect where element are we in on drag and drop so i dont need to use document.getElementById again

Comment: Reference `ev.target` inside of `drop`?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean 'ondragenter' or 'ondrop'?

```
<div id='div1' ondrop="drop1(event)></div>
<script>
function drop1(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.target.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}
</script>
```

Comment: on drop event, so when it's dropped it will detect what element is dropped and add class to it

Comment: well it just same as my code, i don't want to use 'if' conditional but i want it automatically detect the element so i dont need to add div1 etc